# Function which belongs to L2 but not to L5 loc

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a function which belongs to L2 which is not at L5-LOC.
The domain is 0 to infinity. 
I thought about $$ {x}^{-5} $$ . what do you think ?

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^5 = \frac{1}{x^{25}}$. $f^5$ is still integrable around $\infty$, as $f^2$ is; neither $f^5$ nor $f^2$ are integrable around $0$ (i.e., $f$ is not in $L_2$ anyway).

Comment: Surely you know the definition of the spaces involved? Why not test your guess yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variation of the (quite usual) "triangle construction" tailored to $L_2$ and $L_5$ instead of $L_1$ and $L_2$ -- see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794458/if-int-1-infty-fxdx-exist-then-int-1-infty-f2xdx-exist/794463#794463) (you can also adapt the first function in Edwin's comment (comment to the original question) to your question, with the issue now being around $0$ and not $\infty$).